# What is the difference between binary crossentropy and binary crossentropy with logits in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In keras backend we have a flag `with_logits` in [`K.binary_crossentropy`](https://keras.io/backend/#binary_crossentropy). What is the difference between normal binary crossentropy and binary crossentropy with logits? Suppose I am using a seq2seq model and my output sequence is of type `100111100011101`.

What should I use for an recursive LSTM or RNN to learn from this data provided I am giving a similar sequence in the input along with timesteps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether or not you have a sigmoid layer just before the loss function.

If there is a sigmoid layer, it will squeeze the class scores into probabilities, in this case `from_logits` should be `False`. The loss function will transform the probabilities into *logits*, because that's what `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` expects.

If the output is already a logit (i.e. the raw score), pass `from_logits=True`, no transformation will be made.

Both options are possible and the choice depends on your network architecture. By the way if the term *logit* seems scary, take a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean) which discusses it in detail.